# Using Parallel foreach in an API request process?

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous, .net-core, parallel.foreach

It is correct to use a `Parallel.ForEach` while processing a request? I ask this because the `async task` was designed to attendee more requests as possible, not fast as possible which is what `Parallel.ForEach` will do.

Simple example:

```cs
public async Task<OperationResult> ProcessApiRequest(List<string> ids)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(ids, async (id) =>
            {         
                await this.doStuff(id);
                await this.doAnotherStuff(id);
            });

    return OperationResult.Success();
}
```

Imagine I can receive 1 id or 1 million id's, and I want to attendee as much request as possible. Since my threads will be busy processing 1 million id's, it will have struggle attendee new requests, I'm right?

Thank you!

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is meant for data parallelism, not concurrent operations. This call will fire off 1M `async void` calls that nobody will await. It will return almost immediatelly, perhaps before any of the requests had a chance to even start. The compiler will also issue a warning that `ProcessApiRequest` has no await and will run concurrently.

Comment: Yes this is was what I was worried about. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not correct. `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism. It will create as many worker tasks as there are cores on the machine, partition the input data and use one worker per partition. It doesn't know anything about `async` operations, which means your code is essentially :

```
Parallel.ForEach(ids, async void (int id) =>
        {         
            await this.doStuff(id);
            await this.doAnotherStuff(id);
        });
```

On a quad machine, this will fire off 1M requests, 4 at a time, without waiting for any of them. It could easily return before any of the requests had a chance to complete.

If you want to execute multiple requests in a controlled manner, you could use eg an ActionBlock with a specific degree of parallelism, eg :

```
var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
    BoundedCapacity=100
}
var block=new ActionBlock<string>(async id=>{....},options);


foreach(var id in ids)
{
    await block.SendAsync(id);
}
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

The block will process up to 10 concurrent requests. If the actions are really asynchronous, or the async waits are long, we can easily use a higher DOP than the number of available cores.

Input messages are buffered, which means we could end up with 1M requests waiting in the input buffer of a slow block. To avoid this, the `BoundedCapacity` setting will block `SendAsync` if the block can't accept any more inputs.

Finally, the call to `Complete()` tells the block we're done and it should process any remaining messages in its input buffer. We await for them to finish with `await block.Completion`

Comment: In my case, the caller does not need to await the ```await this.doStuff(id)``` or other any operation, and what I return is an ```Acepted``` status code. So here I don't need the ```Parallel.ForEach``` at all because I only need process the "stuff". Thanks for your good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You are right to be concerned, `Parallel.ForEach` by default will use as many threads from the threadpool as it can , the threadpool will scale up gradually to it's maximum thread count of it needs to. `Task.Run` is generally a bad idea for a web server, `Parallel.ForEach` is often many times worse.

Especially given the `ids` is unbounded, you could quickly get to a situation where your requests will get queued as all of the threads are busy satisfying only a handful of requests.

So you are right to be concerned, this sort of code is optimizing the latency of individual requests for very low scale, but at scale will sacrifice a fair and well performing web server, ultimately undoing the latency initial latency win, and creating you a wider service problem.

**Update** - as Panagiotis Kanavos points out in the comments, `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't have `Task` overloads, so will just run the initial synchronous part of the delegate, leaving the bulk of the async work queued up, your API just became fire and forget possibly unknowingly.

For an alternative version using `ChannelReader` & `ChannelWriter` for a completely asynchronous producer consumer pattern, along with some new C# 8.0 syntax, you could try this:

```
public async Task<OperationResult> ProcessApiRequest(List<string> ids)
{
    var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<string>(new BoundedChannelOptions(100) {SingleWriter = true});

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(id); // If the back pressure exceeds 100 ids, we asynchronously wait here
    }
    channel.Writer.Complete();

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) // 8 concurrent readers
    {
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await foreach (var id in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
            {
                await this.doStuff(id);
                await this.doAnotherStuff(id);
            }
        });
    }

    return OperationResult.Success();
}
```

Comment: That's not correct. Parallel.ForEach will create as many worker tasks as there are cores on the machine. It's meant for data paralellism, not concurrent operations, so it makes no sense to use more. The *HUGE* problem is that Parallel.ForEach knows nothing about `async` so *all* of those calls are essentially `async void` calls. They'll all be fired as fast as possible, 4 or 8 at the time, without waiting for any of them to complete

Comment: I hadn't spotted the lack of async delegate overloads, I'll update my answer. Can you point me to the docs that back up the claim that it's the number of cores, other apis do this, but this one uses the default TaskScheduler the docs says which would be unbounded.

Comment: it has nothing to do with APIs or TaskScheduler. There's no `ForEach` overload that accepts a `Task<>`

Comment: I understand that, the bit I am questioning is "Parallel.ForEach will create as many worker tasks as there are cores"

Comment: that's described in the class docs for Parallel and the doc section on [data parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library) and [custom partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl). `Parallel.ForEach` is much more versatile than it looks and it's easy to forget how powerful it is (like I did until I "re"discovered chunk partitioning)

Comment: That doc still talks about TaskScheduler, the default will use Int32.Max concurrency: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.maximumconcurrencylevel?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: what it says is `Behind the scenes, the Task Scheduler partitions the task based on system resources and workload. When possible, the scheduler redistributes work among multiple threads and processors if the workload becomes unbalanced.` It says nothing at all about using 2 billion threads. It says you can customize both partitioning and scheduling, but if you don't the sensible default is to use all cores.

Comment: Frankly, try it. Create a big array with a few million items and run `Parallel.ForEach` on it with some non-IO code. You'll see all cores working at maximum. In this scenario using extra threads will only *slow* things down due to thrashing. The docs explain that partitioning is used to reduce thrashing and synchronization between the workers

Comment: That's what I've just done, it will use all threads in the threadpool, so I think it's less optimal than say 1x number_of_core dedicated threads, it also means threadpool starvation can happen.

Comment: no, it will use all *cores* in the machine, not all 1000s of possible threads in that threadpool. Unless you explicitly increased the DOP, or used blocking code that forced the scheduler to increase the number of workers. All of which are described in the docs

Comment: Yes it will use all cores, but it will use the threadpool (default cap of 200 threads by default)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/slang25/b90586c6c026e23149d223e145235367

Comment: That's not data parallelism. There's no data to partition there. You've already started 1M threads. The only thing this code does is execute 1M blocks, 4/8 at a time. If you want to see how `Parallel` works create an array with 1M random doubles and use `Parallel.ForEach` to calculate their logarithms

Comment: You are confused, you probably have a good point that I don't understand regarding partitioning, but there are not 1M threads being created, the threadpool has a default max.

Comment: No data, no data parallelism. That's an abuse of Parallel. Use a *proper* example instead

Comment: An enumerable of ints is data (add ToArray if you want, it's the same result), `Thread.Sleep` is thread bound work. I honestly don't know what you want, you have the proof, if you wish to convince me I've misinterpreted it then you need to articulate that :) I'd love to understand this better.

Comment: *By default, methods on the Parallel class attempt to use all available processors, are non-cancelable, and target the default TaskScheduler. ParallelOptions enables overriding these defaults.* ([citation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions#remarks))

Comment: Thank you, that was my understanding too